# Laravel pivot table relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot-table, attachment

Today I'm going to list a new problem concerning laravel relations.
There are three tables:

**ALBUM TABLE**

```
Schema::create('albums',  function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->string('name');
          $table->string('slug');
          $table->string('image')->default('default.png');
          $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**PHOTO TABLE**

```
Schema::create('photos', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->string('name');
          $table->string('slug');
          $table->string('image')->default('default.png');
          $table->timestamps();
```

**ALBUM_PHOTO (PIVOT TABLE)**

```
        Schema::create('album_photo',  function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->integer('album_id')->unsigned();
          $table->integer('photo_id')->unsigned();
          $table->timestamps();

          $table->foreign('album_id')->references('id')->on('albums');
          $table->foreign('photo_id')->references('id')->on('photos');
```

In the models we can find the relationship:

**ALBUM**

```
public function photos()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Photo');
  }
```

**PHOTO**

```
public function albums()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Album');
    }
```

The problem arises in the `attach`.
In fact, the images are loaded but are not associated with the `PivotTable`:

```
public function imageupload(Request $request)
    {
      $this->validate($request,[
          'name' => 'required',
          'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg'
      ]);
      // get form image
      $images = $request->file('images');

      $slug = str_slug($request->name);
foreach($images as $image){
      if (isset($image))
      {
//            make unique name for image
          $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
          $imagename = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
//            check album dir is exists
          if (!Storage::disk('public')->exists('photo'))
          {
              Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('photo');
          }
//            resize image for album and upload
          $photo = Image::make($image)->resize(1600,479)->stream();
          Storage::disk('public')->put('photo/'.$imagename,$photo);
          //            check album slider dir is exists
          if (!Storage::disk('public')->exists('photo/slider'))
          {
              Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('photo/slider');
          }
          //            resize image for album slider and upload
          $slider = Image::make($image)->resize(500,333)->stream();
          Storage::disk('public')->put('photo/slider/'.$imagename,$slider);

      } else {
          $imagename = "default.png";
      }
      $photo = new Photo();
      $photo->name = $request->name;
      $photo->slug = $slug;
      $photo->image = $imagename;
      $photo->save();
    /***************************************************/
      $photo->albums()->attach($request->albums);
    /**************************************************/
      Toastr::success('Photo Successfully Saved :)' ,'Success');
    }
      return redirect()->route('admin.album.index');
    }
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks

Comment: $photo->albums()->attach($request->albums);   is $request->albums just an id number?  You only need to attach the id number not the full object.  So in your case it may be $request->albums['id']